# Some Devices are not displaying Message body, only title is visible

Tags: android, android-layout, push-notification, android-notifications

This is how i am displaying Push Notification to user.

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentIntent(intent)
    .setContentTitle("Title")
    .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(msg))
    .setSound(soundUri)
    .build();
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

This is working fine on `Samsung s5`, `Samsung s7`. But on `samsung Note3` , it only displays title, and does not display message body. This may be occurring in some other devices as well.

Kindly guide me that what can be the reason of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(intent)
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(msg))
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                    .setContentText(detail);


    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Yes, it did help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adding `.setContentText(msg)` to your call chain should solve the problem.

[Android documentation for NotificationCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setStyle(android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Style)) states that "If the platform does not provide rich notification styles, [`setStyle(Style style)`] has no effect". I'm going to take a leap of faith and say that this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: ok, so do i need to remove bigText() then? because i added bigText to display text in multi lines

Comment: No :S As i said, whatever you do in `setStyle` will not have ANY affect on SOME devices, i'm just assuming note 3 is one of those devices. But in devices that provide rich notification styles, `setStyle` will work. So removing or keeping bigText() presumably will not affect anything on the note 3

Comment: @Kirmani88 If it answers your question please accept this answer, so that other people who look at this question know that it works.